# Get decimals from Recordset in VBA with ADODB

Tags: vba, excel, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to get a value from a field, I don't know why is rounded

```
rs.Open myQuery, cnn
i = 1
Do While rs.EOF = False
    S1 = rs.Fields("S1") 
    Cells(i, 1) = S1
    i = i + 1
    rs.Next
Loop
```

For example, in the database S1 is 8.567 but I always get 8

Is there a way to define the data type from that field?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the SQL for the recordset?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. The proper way to show your question has been *solved* is to accept the answer that provided the solution (and upvote it as well if you feel it deserves it). We do not put *(Solved)* (or any variety of that) in the titles here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in your query you have to define the type of data you want to have.

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT CAST(F1 AS DOUBLE) AS newValue FROM TABLE"
```

Then you will get newValue with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and assign your variables properly.

```
dim S1 as double   '<~~declare a double-type variable
rs.Open myQuery, cnn
i = 1
With Worksheet("Sheet1")   'define the parent worksheet
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        S1 = CDbl(rs.Fields("S1").Value)  '<~~ force a double-type return and specify the value
        .Cells(i, 1) = S1    '<~~ the prefix period (.) determines that this belongs to Sheet1
        i = i + 1
        rs.Next
    Loop
end with
```

I don't like the orphaned `Cells(i, 1)` either. That should have a defined parent worksheet. Perhaps a wrapping [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) could be used to specify parentage.

Comment: I did what you said but the problem is persisting. Debugging the program, the value for this field is without decimals (before assign the value to the new variable), seems that I can not get decimals from a value that actually doesn't have it. Probably something from my database connection?